# App.xaml.cs OnActivated() is not getting invoked if the application in running as administrator

Tags: c#, wpf

If an application is running as administrator and it is locked by the user then on click the icon from the taskbar the OnActivated(EventArgs e) is not getting invoked.

```
Protected override void OnActivated( EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnActivated(e);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `base.OnActivated(e)` part.

### Explanation

This is the `OnActivated` method in the `Application` ([Application.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Application.cs)):

```cs
protected virtual void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    VerifyAccess();
    if (Activated != null)
    {
        Activated(this, e);
    }
}
```

The problem with calling `base.OnActivated` from the child class, usually `App.xaml.cs`, is that the `Activated` event will fire again which causes a `StackOverflowException`.

In WPF, the application listens to windows messages by calling `EnsureHwndSource` which defines a `HwndWrapperHook` to listen for the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` message.

```cs
// source: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Application.cs

private void EnsureHwndSource()
{
    if (_parkingHwnd == null)
    {
        // _appFilterHook needs to be member variable otherwise
        // it is GC'ed and we don't get messages from HwndWrapper
        // (HwndWrapper keeps a WeakReference to the hook)

        _appFilterHook = new HwndWrapperHook(AppFilterMessage);
        HwndWrapperHook[] wrapperHooks = {_appFilterHook};

        _parkingHwnd = new HwndWrapper(
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        "",
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        wrapperHooks);
    }
}

private IntPtr AppFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    IntPtr retInt = IntPtr.Zero;
    switch ((WindowMessage)msg)
    {
        case WindowMessage.WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
            handled = WmActivateApp(NativeMethods.IntPtrToInt32(wParam));
            break;
        case WindowMessage.WM_QUERYENDSESSION :
            handled = WmQueryEndSession(lParam, ref retInt);
            break;
        default:
            handled = false;
            break;
    }
    return retInt;
}

private bool WmActivateApp(Int32 wParam)
{
    int temp = wParam;
    bool isActivated = (temp == 0? false : true);

    // Event handler exception continuality: if exception occurs in Activate/Deactivate event handlers, our state would not
    // be corrupted because no internal state are affected by Activate/Deactivate. Please check Event handler exception continuality
    // if a state depending on those events is added.
    if (isActivated == true)
    {
        OnActivated(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    else
    {
        OnDeactivated(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can see in `WmActivateApp` that it calls `OnActivated` which raised the `Activated` event that our descendent `Application` class handles.

If you put a breakpoint on the first line of the `OnActivated` event handler inside `App.xaml.cs`, you can see the following call stack:

[image]

By calling `base.OnActivated(e)` in that event handler, the `Activated` event will fire again, at which point our `Activated` handler will handle the event which calls the `base.OnActivated(e)` and that infinite loops causes the `StackOverflowException`.

### Alternatives

Instead of adding the `Activated` event handler in the XAML (see below), we can instead just `override` the base's `OnActivated` method. Basically, change this:

```xml
<Application x:Class="TestWpfApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Activated="App_OnActivated">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To this:

```xml
<Application x:Class="TestWpfApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

In the code-behind (`App.xaml.cs`) add the `OnActivated` override.

```cs
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnActivated(e);

    // do whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Your post got flagged for being too short. Please add some details about why you believe this action solves the problem. Normally, you want to call into base to allow existing behavior. If you don't, you will be overriding what happens in base and that needs to be accounted for. They might need to copy commands out of base so they are not lost by this omission.

Comment: @HackSlash I would have made it a comment if I were allowed to leave comments. `OnActivated` raises the `Activated` event which causes a `StackOverflowException` since it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @HackSlash Added the explanation. Calling that depends on whether you are overriding the `OnActivated` method or you're handling the `Activated` event. If it's the latter, you'll get a `StackOverflowException`. if you're overriding the `virtual` method, then I agree.

I based my answer on the fact that they were not actually using the `override` and were instead handling the event (e.g. `Activated="App_OnActivated"` in `App.xaml`). Considering their code they provided had `Protected` and not `protected` they clearly didn't copy their actual code and that infinite loop seemed most likely.